# Changing key type on JSON dictionary

Tags: json, swift

I've encountered a JSON response that's not like any I'm accustomed to working with. Intead of key-value pairs down the line, there's a section where there's a dictionary of with `String` keys and `Int` values. I'd like to decode the string key from the dictionary as a `Date` object.

Here's the JSON in question:

```
[
    {
        "country": "Afghanistan",
        "province": null,
        "timeline": {
            "cases": {
                "5/22/20": 9216,
                "5/23/20": 9998,
                "5/24/20": 10582
            },
            "deaths": {
                "5/22/20": 205,
                "5/23/20": 216,
                "5/24/20": 218
            },
            "recovered": {
                "5/22/20": 996,
                "5/23/20": 1040,
                "5/24/20": 1075
            }
        }
    },
]
```

Here's what I wrote for Codable structs to decode it:

```
struct HistoricCountry: Codable {
    let country: String
    let province: String?
    let timeline: Timeline
}

struct Timeline: Codable {
    let cases, deaths, recovered: [String: Int]
}
```

Here's the code I wrote to decode it. This works if I leave the `Timeline` as a dictionary keyed as a string/int key-value pair, the JSON decodes properly:

```
do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "M/dd/yy"
    decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(formatter)

    let decodedElements = try decoder.decode([HistoricCountry].self, from: data)
    XCTAssertEqual(decodedElements.count, 266)
} catch {
    XCTFail("\n Decoding failed :\n\(error)")
}
```

If I change the `Timeline` key value pairs to `[Date: Int]`:

```
struct Timeline: Codable {
    let cases, deaths, recovered: [Date: Int]
}
```

I get this error:

```
 Decoding failed :
typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "timeline", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "cases", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: Yes, it's an abbreviated version of the JSON. Instead of a string representing a date as a key value, I'd like to decode the string value as a `Date` object.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. You cannot decode a dictionary **key** to `Date`. The date decoding strategy can only affect **values**

Comment: Oof...I could do a computed var that goes over the dictionaries and dumps the key/value pairs in a tuple or something, though, right?

Comment: Yes, but that's inefficient, You could implement `init(from decoder)` and decode the keys yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot decode JSON *keys* with a decoding strategy.

The following code can be certainly optimized but this maps the string keys to `Date`

```
struct Timeline: Codable {

    let formatter : DateFormatter = {
        let fm = DateFormatter()
        fm.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        fm.dateFormat = "M/dd/yy"
        return fm
    }()

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case cases, deaths, recovered }
    let cases, deaths, recovered: [Date: Int]

    init(from decoder : Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let casesData = try container.decode([String: Int].self, forKey: .cases)
        var caseResult = [Date:Int]()
        for (key, value) in casesData {
            let date = formatter.date(from: key)!
            caseResult[date] = value
        }
        cases = caseResult

        let deathsData = try container.decode([String: Int].self, forKey: .deaths)
        var deathsResult = [Date:Int]()
        for (key, value) in deathsData {
            let date = formatter.date(from: key)!
            deathsResult[date] = value
        }
        deaths = deathsResult

        let recoveredData = try container.decode([String: Int].self, forKey: .recovered)
        var recoveredResult = [Date:Int]()
        for (key, value) in recoveredData {
            let date = formatter.date(from: key)!
            recoveredResult[date] = value
        }

        recovered = recoveredResult
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Codable only supports Strings and Ints as keys for keyed containers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/keyeddecodingcontainer), so it's not possible to use a `Date` as the key. (If you try, it attempts to decode an array of the format `[key1, value1, key2, value2, ...]`, which explains the error you were getting).

What you *can* do is use a property wrapper which encodes and decodes as `[String:Int]` and converts the strings to and from dates:

```
import Foundation

let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "M/dd/yy"
    return formatter
}()

@propertyWrapper
struct DateKeyed<T> {
    var wrappedValue: [Date: T]
}

extension DateKeyed: Encodable where T: Encodable {
    enum EncodingError: Error {
        case duplicateKey
    }
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        try Dictionary(
            wrappedValue.map { (dateFormatter.string(from: $0.key), $0.value) },
            uniquingKeysWith: { _, _ in throw EncodingError.duplicateKey }
        ).encode(to: encoder)
    }
}

extension DateKeyed: Decodable where T: Decodable {
    enum DecodingError: Error {
        case duplicateKey
        case invalidDate(String)
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let dict = try [String:T](from: decoder)
        try self.init(wrappedValue: Dictionary(
            dict.map {
                guard let date = dateFormatter.date(from: $0.key) else { throw DecodingError.invalidDate($0.key) }
                return (date, $0.value)
            },
            uniquingKeysWith: { _, _ in throw DecodingError.duplicateKey }
        ))
    }
}

struct Timeline: Codable {
    @DateKeyed var cases: [Date:Int]
}

let encoder = JSONEncoder()
encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
try print(String(data: encoder.encode(Timeline(cases: [Date(): 5, Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 0): 10])), encoding: .utf8)!)
```

Output:

```
{
  "cases" : {
    "5\/25\/20" : 5,
    "12\/31\/00" : 10
  }
}
```